# Keycloak: On wrong OTP it redirects to username-password form, not showing Phone username password form

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-spi, keycloak-authorization-services

I'm using cutom Providers and SPI using [keycloak-phone-provider](https://github.com/cooperlyt/keycloak-phone-provider),

I have configured browser flow for client as below:

[image]

After this it shows what we expect.

[image]

But when we give wrong OTP, it redirects and shows username-password form:

http://localhost:8180/realms/hc-realm/login-actions/authenticate?execution=60fbe0b2-0dbb-445c-8751-54ee28c4316e&client_id=hc-client&tab_id=ieKqIWvOTnk

[image]

Is there a way where we can configure login actions in keycloak. Currently, I'm using keycloak version 21.